# Overflow error in Python Code for Maximum Subarray Using Recursion

Tags: python, runtime-error, overflow, max, sub-array

My program seems to not work for this code. I'm new to Python so I'm not sure if this is a language related error. I'm currently using Python 2.7.8.

```
    A = [-1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6]

    def main():
        a,b,c = find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A)                                                   
        print a,b,c

    def find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid,  high):

        #mid = math.floor((low + high)//2)
        left_sum = float("-inf")
        sum = 0
        i = mid
        max_left = 0
        for i in range (mid, low, -1):
            sum = sum + A[i]
            if sum > left_sum:
                 left_sum = sum
                 max_left = i

        right_sum = float("-inf")
        sum = 0
        j = mid + 1
        max_right = 0
        for j in range (mid + 1, high):
            sum = sum + A[j]
            if sum > right_sum:
                 right_sum = sum
                 max_right = j
        return (max_left, max_right, left_sum + right_sum)


    def find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low = 0, high = -1):
        high = len(A)
        if high == low:
            return (low, high, A[low])
        else:
            mid = math.floor((low + high) // 2)
            left_low, left_high, left_sum = find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low, mid)
            right_low, right_high, right_sum = find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, mid + 1, high)
            cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid,  high)
            if left_sum >= right_sum & left_sum >= cross_sum:
                return (left_low, left_high, left_sum)
            elif right_sum >= left_sum & right_sum >= cross_sum:
                return (right_low, right_high, right_sum)
            else:
                return (cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum)

    if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

The function find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid,  high) is working fine but for the life of me I can't seem to find the error with the function find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low, high). Its causing the program to overflow. I don't understand if there is a problem with the logic or the syntax. I would really appreciate it if someone could please explain this to me. Many thanks!

Comment: What error message are you getting? `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`? Something else?

Comment: The error that it's throwing, and an example of input you're using would help a lot

Comment: I'm having to kill the program, it just says error in the line at which I make the recursive call the first time. I edited my code and added the input. This is my first time on StackOverflow too so sorry for the clumsiness.

Comment: So it says "error" and nothing else at all? That's very strange. Also, please check the indentation in the code you've posted here. I tried running it and got `IndentationError: expected an indented block` because `def main():` and `a,b,c = max_subarray(A)` have the same amount of indentation.

Comment: ok I will check again.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake while pasting the code here. It's correct in the Idle editor I'm currently using. Have modified it now.

Comment: Ok, we're making progress :-) Still a few problems, though. 1) `if sum > right_sum:` whose following line has the same indentation; 2) `if high == low:` and the lines following it, which looks like they should be part of `find_maximum_subarray_recursive`, but are indented wrong, if so; and 3) `max_subarray`, which is called in `main` but never defined anywhere.

Comment: The error I get:  File "D:\dc_algorithms (2).py", line 70, in find_maximum_subarray_recursive
    left_low, left_high, left_sum = find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low, mid)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @Kevin I modified the indentation. And you were right about the recursion error in your first comment. How do I solve this?

Comment: I still can't run your code because of problems 1) and 3) from my last comment, so I can only give general advice here. "maximum recursion depth exceeded" happens when a function calls itself one thousand times. Sometimes this means your program would have kept running forever if the interpreter hadn't stepped in and stopped it; but sometimes the program would have finished just fine if only you had a little more recursion depth. You could try calling [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) if you think you're in the latter case.

Comment: @Kevin I corrected 1) and 3). I really don't understand why my function is calling itself 1000 times. What do you mean by 'if only you had a little more recursion depth' ? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low = 0, high = -1):
    high = len(A)
```

This `high = len(A)` line looks like a logic error to me. I'm guessing your original reasoning was, "if the user doesn't supply a value for the `high` parameter, then we'll supply it for him as the highest index that `A` can accept". If that's your intention, there's two problems:

1. you set the value regardless of whether or not the user supplied a value himself.
2. the highest index `A` can accept is `len(A)-1`, not `len(A)`.

Ignoring the user's supplied value of `high` is the cause of your infinite loop. For example, `find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, 0, 6)` calculates a `mid` of 3 and calls `find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, 0, 3)` in order to find `left_sum`. But that 3 value is thrown away and replaced with a 6. So the next function calculates a `mid` of 3 and calls `find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, 0, 3)`... And so on, forever and ever.

So I think the beginning of the function should look more like:

```
def find_maximum_subarray_recursive(A, low = 0, high = -1):
    if high == -1: high = len(A)-1
```

---

And another thing:

```
    else:
        mid = math.floor((low + high) // 2)
```

This looks like a type error to me. `math.floor` returns a floating point value, but `mid` should be an integer (since you're going to use it to index a list in the future, and lists only accept integers). You don't really need the `math.floor` call at all. The `//` operator already returns an integer. I think this line should look more like:

```
mid = (low + high) // 2
```

---

These changes don't entirely fix the program. You'll get a result of `2 3 7`, but 7 isn't the maximum subarray sum for `A`. The largest sum is 8, from the subarray [3, 4, -5, 6].

But at least you're not overflowing any more!

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I have to figure out why its not calculating correctly. I have followed the algorithm from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.

Comment: Ok so when I change the recursive call: cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid,  high) to cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid,  high + 1), it works. Thanks @Kevin for all your help! :)